# How to "force selection" with YUI 3 Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, yui, yui3

I am using YUI 3 to create an autocomplete box in which I would like to force the selection and require the user to select a result from the container, or else the input field is cleared of whatever value they have typed in manually.
`forceSelection`was a feature in the `YUI 2 Autocomplete widget` and info [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/#force). 
But... it does not look like it has been added to the new `YUI` 3 version yet.[here's](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/ticket/2528855) the open ticket.
I would just use YUI 2 Autocomplete, however I am already using other improved features that came with YUI 3.

Is there an easy way to implement this manually for YUI 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ryan Grove from the YUI team recently posted this:

> This feature is currently targeted for 3.5.0.
>   In the meantime, it's not too hard to implement forced selection by hooking into AutoComplete events.
>   Here's a very basic example that you could build on:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/rgrove/aJcqt/